# julia create symbol with greek capital letters?

Tags: julia

How can i create a symbol with  greek capital letters,such as:

`@vars θ uppercase("θ")`

it expected to create two symbols : lowercase letter θ and uppercase letter Θ,

however the output is:

`(θ,)`,which means the uppercase letter symbol wasn't created.

Comment: What is `@vars` coming from?

Comment: It's coming from package SymPy. I am just doing some formula derivation .Thank you for your comment.  @fredrikekre

Answer (score 3):

Easy enough: in your REPL enter `\theta <tab>` for lowercase theta, `\Theta <tab>` for uppercase. Similar for all other greek letters, for example: *gamma*

[image: Example for lower& uppercase gamma]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it works. I have typed `\<tab>` to find Θ, but i missed `\Theta`.

Comment: Hey @KnightSpark, great that made it work. If your question is clear now, please tag my answer as accepted answer. Thank you

Comment: I'm a new user of stackoverflow, I don't how to accept your answer;Under upvote and downvote arrows only have"share" and "edit" links.

Comment: No problem, check out this description: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. In short, there should be a grey acception mark next to my answer, which you be able to click to effectively accept this answer